# What is Wrong with the for Loops

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, subprocess, stdout

I can't get an output from this code, it is just looping infinitely I guess, it has to readlines and append those lines to the list named data, but it doesn't give an output, what have I done wrong?
Any suggestions will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
import os
import subprocess
import commands

command = ['sudo', 'iwlist', 'wlan0', 'scan']
output = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.readlines()
data = []
for item in output:
      if item.strip().startswith('ESSID:'):
           data = (item.lstrip('ESSID:').rstrip('\n'))
      for item in output:
            if item.strip().startswith('Quality:'):
                 data.append('Quality:')
            for item in output:
                  if item.strip().startswith('Pairwise:'):
                       data.append('Pairwise:')
                       print data
```

Comment: What do you see when you `print output` immediately after `readlines()`? Also, what does your expected output look like?

Comment: sudo requires a password so `Popen` never returns

Comment: I am checking it now @Cyber , no command is working, problem is with the loops after 'ESSID:'

Comment: @Cyber it prints the iwlist in a unformed formation, but it's the output of "sudo iwlist wlan0 scan"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below, I don't think you need multiple `for` loops.

Also, the command `iwlist` works without `sudo` permissions as well, so you should cut it out (since you won't be able to enter the sudo password with `subprocess.PIPE`)

I've also removed `os`, `commands` modules which though imported are not being used anywhere.

```
import subprocess

command = ['iwlist', 'wlan0', 'scan']
output = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.readlines()
data = []
for item in output:
    if item.strip().startswith('ESSID:'):
         data.append([item.lstrip('ESSID:').rstrip('\n')])
    if item.strip().startswith('Quality:'):
        data.append('Quality:')
    if item.strip().startswith('Pairwise:'):
        data.append('Pairwise:')
print data
```

***EDIT***

Since you want to read each of the connections, try this one

```
import subprocess

command = ['sudo', '-S', 'iwlist', 'wlan0', 'scan']
output = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
data = []
for cell_item in output.split("Cell"):
    data_item = []
    for line in cell_item.split("\n"):
        if any(item in line for item in ["ESSID", "Quality", "Pairwise"]):
            data_item.append(line.strip())
    if data_item:
        data.append(data_item)
print data
```

The trick here is to split the output by cells first (based on output of iwlist on my system), and then, within each of the cell, you can check for `Quality, Pairwise, ESSID`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes iwlist works without sudo you are right, but I need to run it with sudo to see all cells I can see, without sudo I can only see the one I am connected.

Comment: It has the same problem as my earlier code, it only prints ESSID, Quality and Pairwise lines doesn't work

Comment: @TolgaVarol Check edits, you will be prompted to enter the password in current version. Dont forget to accept and upvote if my answer helped.

Comment: @TolgaVarol I've also taken the liberty to do away with multiple `lstrip` and `rstrip` with `strip`

Comment: Thank you for your edit, why would I be prompted to enter the password? , your edit works great and one more thing I would like to ask you I tried another code and it only prints the ESSID and the address can you check that too if you have time, I was working on it but I couldn't understand why, I am a bit new to programming, yes the lstrip and rstrip's were a big problem.

Comment: @TolgaVarol I see that you've posted that as an answer. Delete that answer, and ask it as a new question.